# How to get a hash of an instance's all attr_accessor fields?

Tags: ruby, oop, attributes

We have a class with `attr_accessor`s. Such as:

```
class Class
  attr_accessor :x
  attr_accessor :y

  ...

end
```

I want to create a hash from an instance of this class. Such as:

```
c.to_attr_hash = { :x => "x", :y => "y" }
```

How could this be done?

Comment: The "duplicate" question list attr_accessors in an array. This question wants a hash of attr_accessor and their values, which has answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165776/11520747.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Class
  attr_accessor :x
  attr_accessor :y

  def to_attr_hash
    hash = Hash.new
    instance_variables.each do |v|
      hash[v] = instance_variable_get(v)
    end
    hash
  end
end

c = Class.new

c.x = 'a'
c.y = 'b'

p c.to_attr_hash

#=> {:@x=>"a", :@y=>"b"}
```

Comment: A bit more concise (and more ruby like) solution would be: `instance_variables.each_with_object({}) { |var, hash| hash[var] = instance_variable_get(var) }`

Comment: This lists the instance variables, not the `attr_accessor`s. By the way, monkey-patching core classes such as `Class` should only be done *veeeeery* carefully, and if there is really no other choice.

Comment: Try `c = Class.new; c.instance_variable_set(:@i_am_not_an_attr_accessor, 42); c.to_attr_hash`, and you will see that none of the two `attr_accessor`s show up whereas something which is *not* an `attr_accessor` *does* show up.