# Converting a class into a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert any class into a hash using ruby. The initial implementation I have done:

```
class Object
    def to_hash
        instance_variables.map{ |v| 
            Hash[v.to_s.delete("@").to_sym, instance_variable_get(v)] }.inject(:merge)
   end
end
```

Everything seemed to work ok. But when I tried the following code:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :pet
    def initialize(name, pet)
       @name = name
       @pet = pet
    end
end

class Pet
    attr_accessor :name, :age 
    def initialize(name, age)
       @name = name
       @age = age
    end
end


tom =  Person.new("Tom", Pet.new("Tobby", 5))
puts tom.to_hash
```

I have got the following output

```
{:name=>"Tom", :pet=>#<Pet:0x0055ff94072378 @name="Tobby", @age=5>}
```

I am unable to hash the attribute pet of type Pet (or any other custom class)

Any ideas?

**Edit**
That's what I would expect to be returned:

```
{:name=>"Tom", :pet=>{ :name=>"Tobby", :age=>5}}
```

Comment: This is what I'd expect without using a recursive `to_hash`. There's no code that says each instance variable should also run `to_hash`.

Comment: What would you expect to be returned?

Comment: I tried to add the code but I am unsure how...

Comment: See my first comment: there is currently no reason the code would call `to_hash` on the iterated instance variables. If you want to call `to_hash` on instance variables you need to call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to have associated objects to be returned as a hash too hen you have to call `to_hash` recursively:

```
class Object
  def to_hash
    return self if instance_variables.empty?

    instance_variables
      .map { |v| [v.to_s.delete("@").to_sym, instance_variable_get(v).to_hash] }
      .to_h
  end
end

tom =  Person.new("Tom", Pet.new("Tobby", 5))
puts tom.to_hash
#=> { :name=>"Tom", :pet => { :name=>"Tobby", :age=>5 } }
```

Comment: `"Tom".to_hash` would return `nil` – you have to handle the "core" classes separately.

Comment: Yup; would need (at least) a `respond_to?`, with the caveat that `to_hash` lives in a few places already.

Comment: Something like `class String ; def to_hash ; self ; end ; end` would be another option if you prefer the OOP way :-)

Comment: Yes! That's exactly What I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: @spickermann What happens when is tom =  Person.new("Tom", [Pet.new("Tobby", 5)])

Comment: If you want to cover cases like that too then you need to override that method on `Enumerable` or `Array`. There are probably more edge cases for which a simple method on `Object` is not the right solution.